# What softwares I can use to make animated illustrations for math and physics?

Tags: math-software

I am interested to know what software can help do physical and mathematical illustrations.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ly4S0oi3Yz8

I know GeoGabra but I don`t know the 3D option in it. any suggestions?

thank you

Comment: The word "animated" appears in the title, but not in the body of your Question.  I suspect this is a critical requirement for you, but to be on-topic here there needs to be a close connection with a mathematical problem to be solved.  In its current form I don't know what to make of your request.  Linking to a YouTube video is not a substitute for explaining the problem in your own words.

Comment: The software in the video is Manim, an opensource library for "programming" animations.